# Clarification on a Claim in Black-Scholes-Merton Derivation

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, european-options, black-scholes-merton

In these notes: https://johnthickstun.com/docs/bscrr.pdf, towards the end of the proof of **Proposition 5.2** on page 6, the author claims:

$$
\log 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Bbb{E}_\pi \left[\frac {S^*_n} S \right] =
\log 
\Bbb{E}_\nu \left[\frac {S^*} S \right]
$$

I.e., that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}_\pi \left[\frac {S^*_n} S \right] =
\mathbb{E}_\nu \left[\frac {S^*} S \right]
$$

I'm not entirely following why that's true. In **Proposition 4.2**, the author does prove that

$$
\log \frac {S^*_n} S \xrightarrow [n \to \infty] {d} \mathcal{N}(\nu T, \sigma^2 T)
$$

in *distribution* (weakly), but that's weaker than convergence in mean, which is what he seems to be using. He does refer to **Proposition 4.1**, but **Proposition 4.1** talks about the log-returns, not the returns, and in any case, doesn't speak to the limit. So even if I try to compute the expected value of $\frac {S^*_n} S$ with respect to the risk-neutral probability measure $\pi$ directly, it ends up being $\mathbb{E}_\pi \left[\frac {S^*_n} S \right] = T \log r$, which he already has. What am I missing?